# Python - Filter nested inside of map produces unexpected output

Tags: python, filter, functional-programming, iterator

I have a list of filenames (strings) and and a set ls consisting of floats. Initially I want to filter all files that match each element of ls according to a predetemined expression:
I convert all floats that are actually integers to integers and feed that into `.format` to create an appropriate search string (`exprs`). This produces the expected sequence of strings. I now want to filter 'files' using re.search, but as I understand it I need a different filter for each output of exprs. So I nested this inside of a map function:

```
t = 'Matrix'
exprs = map('{}_spike_{}_D1_1'.format , cycle([t]) ,(int(x) if x.is_integer() else x for x in ls))
y = map(lambda f:filter(lambda i : re.search(f,i), files), exprs)
```

`Print(next(exprs))` produces the expected output i.e. `'Matrix_spike_50_D1_1'`. If i 'freeze' the expression in re.search i.e. by doing `b = next(exprs)` and `re.search(b, [...])` I get the expected output (i.e. the filename, correctly selected).
But when I try to use `map` to consume all outputs of `exprs` and return resulting `filter([...])`'s I get

1. a filter object instead of a map object
2. two *identical* filter objects ,when running it exchaustively by means of a `while True`, catching all `StopIterations` and resuming

How can I modify this to return files that filter returns for each exprs?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have a list of files such as:

```
files = ['a', 'b', 'Matrix_spike_2_D1_1', 'c', 'Matrix_spike_4_D1_1']
```

and a list of floating point numbers, which should be integers (but maybe not all of them are):

```
ls = [1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

From the `ls` list of numbers that are integers, you construct the names 'Matrix_spike_2_D1_1', 'Matrix_spike_3_D1_1', etc. and then select from the `files` list those files that satisfy the `rex.search` call. Of course, method `search` without using `^` and `$` anchors will not be doing a full match, so I wonder whether you really meant to be using the `fullmatch` method.

First, you have:

```
t = 'Matrix'
exprs = map('{}_spike_{}_D1_1'.format , cycle([t]) ,(int(x) if x.is_integer() else x for x in ls))
```

I believe this is simplified to:

```
exprs = map('Matrix_spike_{}_D1_1'.format, (int(x) for x in ls if x.is_integer())
```

And note that I am only selecting values from `ls` that are integers, which I believe is your intention. To go with your approach, I believe the simplest remedy is to define a function `filter_func`:

```
import re


ls = [1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
files = ['a', 'b', 'Matrix_spike_2_D1_1', 'c', 'Matrix_spike_4_D1_1']
exprs = list(map(re.compile, map('Matrix_spike_{}_D1_1'.format, (int(x) for x in ls if x.is_integer()))))

def filter_func(f):
    for expr in exprs:
        if expr.search(f):
            return True
    return False

matched_files = list(filter(filter_func, files))
print(matched_files)
```

Prints:

```
['Matrix_spike_2_D1_1', 'Matrix_spike_4_D1_1']
```

Or with a more "functional" but perhaps less efficient approach:

```
import re
import operator
import functools


ls = [1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
files = ['a', 'b', 'Matrix_spike_2_D1_1', 'c', 'Matrix_spike_4_D1_1']
exprs = list(map(re.compile, map('Matrix_spike_{}_D1_1'.format, (int(x) for x in ls if x.is_integer()))))
filter_func = lambda f: functools.reduce(operator.or_, map(lambda expr: bool(expr.search(f)), exprs), False)
matched_files = list(filter(filter_func, files))
print(matched_files)
```

Prints:

```
['Matrix_spike_2_D1_1', 'Matrix_spike_4_D1_1']
```

But I believe your approach is not the most efficient. You should be doing instead a single regular expression search against each element of your `files` list. In the example above, that regular expression would be:

```
rex = re.compile('Matrix_spike_(?:2|3|4|5)_D1_1')
```

In the regular expression above you would be matching each element of the `files` list against all 4 possible file names you are looking for.  That reduces the code to:

```
import re


ls = [1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
files = ['a', 'b', 'Matrix_spike_2_D1_1', 'c', 'Matrix_spike_4_D1_1']
sub_rex = '|'.join(str(int(x)) for x in ls if x.is_integer())
rex = re.compile('Matrix_spike_(?:' +  sub_rex + ')_D1_1');
matched_files = list(filter(rex.search, files))
print(matched_files)
```

Prints:

```
['Matrix_spike_2_D1_1', 'Matrix_spike_4_D1_1']
```

If you mean to be doing a full match (equality) against file names, then the following code would be the most efficient because it adds the names you are looking for to a set and each comparison will be a constant-time lookup:

```
ls = [1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
files = ['a', 'b', 'Matrix_spike_2_D1_1', 'c', 'Matrix_spike_4_D1_1']
sought_files = {f'Matrix_spike_{int(x)}_D1_1' for x in ls if x.is_integer()}
matched_files = list(filter(lambda f: f in sought_files, files))
print(matched_files)
```